# Recover GDrive Folder from Crashed Computer

Tags: crash, google-drive, recovery

I'll state first, that I know this may sound awful given the implications. But anyways I still need a solution.

A client of mine suffer a crash on his computer and now its not bootable, inside was a GDrive folder, that stoped syncing about a month ago.

Needless to say, he needs the files in that gdrive folder for his work, and since they are not on the cloud, I need to get them from the local folder.

Thing is, I can't, the folder wont allow copy, I'm guessing its a security feature, so, I ask the horrible question, is it possible to circumvent it?

Or, is there a way to open the folder in another computer, like, if the other PC had logged into the gdrive account?

Or, is there a tool for this?

Comment: You will have to provide us more information other then "I can't copy the files", unless EFS was used, there isn't any reason the files contained in the directory cannot be copied (unless they are corrupted).  Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope (by the way).  If EFS was enabled, and your client does not have the certificate used to encrypt the files, then the files cannot be recovered (due to the fact they are encrypted).

Comment: "The folder won't allow copy" in what specific circumstances?  Did you extract the HD, put it into a USB enclosure, plug it into another PC, and be successful at navigating most of the HD except for the Google Drive folder?

Comment: I thought the point of gdrive was to keep a copy on the cloud... even an old copy's better than no copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little ashamed of myself. It was a simple permissions problem. The first time I tried it, was on a hurry, with the client breathing down my neck, and with a time limit.

Now that I do it in the calm of my own office, I fully read the messages and found the answer.

Curiously, only the GDrive folder had special owner/permission combination. Since I could read all the rest of the files with no problem (all other files I managed to copy quickly). That's when I thought it must have some sort of special security feature or something of the like.

Thank you for your insight, it helped me re-do the process properly. Basically, you woke me up.